# Error: Call to a member function funcName on null

Tags: php

I'm using Codeception with wpbrowser to test a class but can't test an object instance of a class.

The error is  Call to a member function funcName on null (shown in red in the codeception CLI). It only happens when testing the object. The static method test works/passes.

Anyone know what causes this?

```
class A {
  public function run() {
    return 'run fired';
  }

  public static function runStatic() {
    return 'run static';
  } 
}

$a = new A();


class AjaxResponderTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\WPTestCase {

    public function setUp(): void {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function tearDown(): void {
        parent::tearDown();
    }

  public function testA() {
    global $a;
    $result = $a->run();

    // [Error] Call to a member function run() on null
    $this->assertEquals('run fired', $result);
  }

  public function testAStatic() {
    $this->assertEquals('run static', A::runStatic()); // test passes
  }
}
```

Copying @Mike Foxtech's test class, I get these errors in the console:

```
1) AjaxResponderTest: A
 Test  tests/wpunit/AjaxResponderTest.php:testA

  [PHPUnit\Framework\Exception] array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array  

#1  Codeception\Subscriber\ErrorHandler->errorHandler

---------
2) AjaxResponderTest: A static
 Test  tests/wpunit/AjaxResponderTest.php:testAStatic

  [PHPUnit\Framework\Exception] array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array  

#1  Codeception\Subscriber\ErrorHandler->errorHandler

ERRORS!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 0, Errors: 2.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using global var? is that for specific reason? Usually it is better to avoid using global vars.

Anyway I'm not familiar with Codeception, however it is obvious that your variable $a is has no value during the test run-time. 
I would move the class instantiation to the setUp() function and not outside of the test.

Comment: putting `$a = new A();` in setUp() doesn't work (same error) but putting it inside the test method does, thanks

Comment: Yes, when a variable is declared inside a function it is *scoped* to that function, and is only visible inside the function. For sharing data between two functions of the same class you can use a **class property**.

Comment: Hi, as bdsl said you should have used class properties, I thought it was clear - my bad.
You have to declare $a as a class property,then on the setUp function use $this->a = new A(); 
Another thing, use the class property and the setUp function only if you are going to use $a multiple times in your class. if it will be in use only once, then you can create it in the specific function where its due.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
class AjaxResponderTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\WPTestCase {

    protected $glob;

    public function setUp(): void {
        parent::setUp();
        global $GLOBALS;
        $this->glob = &$GLOBALS;
    }

    public function tearDown(): void {
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function testA() {
        $result = $this->glob['a']->run();

        // [Error] Call to a member function run() on null
        $this->assertEquals('run fired', $result);
    }

    public function testAStatic() {
        $this->assertEquals('run static', A::runStatic()); // test passes
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I get an error regarding array_merge() shown in full above.

Comment: New error message: Undefined index 'a'. I then tried logging $GLOBALS in the outermost scope but gave up after the terminal printed stuff for 10+ seconds. I then tried moving your setup inside of the test method testA() but same undefined index error. I suspect Codeception isn't attaching $a to the globals array properly for some reason. Thank you regardless